# Why isnt the bind working? Is any other way to identify each image sepparately?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to generate a new image on each click to a button, i do the binding but it seems to not work in any case.
I save each new image on a global array "imagenes_mostradas", and then create the image and the binging, the image appears nice, but no effect when clic. Thanks for your help

```
def on_clic(event): #CAMBIAR TAG A VARAIBLE GLOBAL CON CUENTA ABSOLUTA 
    imagenes_mostradas.insert(len(imagenes_mostradas),ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "/home/jose/Escritorio/qemu-int-main/P3_SysTimer_3b/IMG/led.png"))
    canvas.create_image(20, 20, image=imagenes_mostradas[len(imagenes_mostradas)-1],tags=len(imagenes_mostradas))
    canvas.tag_bind(len(imagenes_mostradas)-1,"<Button-1>",lambda event: on_motion(event,imagenes_mostradas[len(imagenes_mostradas)-1]))

def on_motion(event,imagen):
    imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "/home/jose/Escritorio/qemu-int-main/P3_SysTimer_3b/IMG/led.png")
    canvas.create_image(250,280,image=imagen)
```

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ [mcve]. It needs to still be minimal, but we need to be able to reproduce the problem. I can see right off the bat, though, that  you're probably not binding to what you think you're binding too. `len(imagenes_mostradas)-1` probably doesn't relate to the id of the object created on the canvas since you create more canvas items than there are items in the list.